# Hermit reasoner getEquivalentClasses

Tags: owl, ontology

i have ontology with VALIDITY as top class with two subclasse CAR_PROPERTY and VEHICLE_TYPE

THING
 - VALIDITY 
  VALIDITY hasSubcls CAR_PROPERTY haSubcls SPEED  hasSubcls SPD130 hasSubcls SPD120 hasSubcls SPD110 
 
  VALIDITY hasSubcls VEHICLE_TYPE disjointUnionIf(BUS,CAR,TRUCK)

**When i call** hermit.getEquivalentClasses(intersectionOf(SPD130, SPD120, SPD110)) i get what i expect - **SPD110** , however result of **hermit.getEquivalentClasses(intersectionOf(SPD130, SPD120, SPD110, CAR))** is **intersectionOf(SPD130, SPD120, SPD110, CAR)** but i expect **intersectionOf(SPD110, CAR)** . 
 What is wrong in my ontology?
  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if

`intersectionOf(SPD130, SPD120, SPD110, CAR) equivalentTo intersectionOf(SPD110, CAR)`

is entailed. I believe it should be.

I do not think there is anything wrong in your ontology, it's just that HermiT does not have an obligation to remove redundant terms from an expression, so it leaves the expression as it is.

Comment: indeed it isEntailed, which helps me partially cos now i can tell which class expression are equivalent. However i would also like hermit to tell me the "shortest" equivalent class expression to given calss expression, in other words to simplify the expression. Is he capable doing it? thanks a lot!

Comment: HermiT is likely doing this job in its internals, but there is no access to those structures through the OWLReasoner interface